# What do you call love at first sight if you haven't seen her yet?

Tags: meaning

With love at first sight you both see each other.

But if she already saw you and fell in love and you didn't see her and all she left was her voice and you never heard of her before... but you'd love to listen to her. how do you fall in love with her?

What is it called if you haven't seen her but it's similar to "love at first sight"?

Comment: "A mistake"? "A learning experience"?

Comment: Blind captivation...?

Comment: What you describe is a shallow kind of infatuation (an initial reaction based only on appearance of voice).  Is that your intention?  For example, Gary's suggestion of soulmate could refer to people who have never seen each other; perhaps just corresponded.  But that would imply feelings based on something much deeper than superficial characteristics.  Is the term you're looking for specifically superficial, or anything that does not involve sight?

Answer (score 3):

> What is it called if you haven't seen her but it's similar to "love at
>   first sight"?

It's called ***love sight unseen***.

> **sight unseen**
>   Without seeing the object in question: *bought the horse sight unseen*.
>
> [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sight+unseen)

---

Usage examples:

> To fall in love sight unseen — it's like something from a mediaeval
>   romance, isn't it?
>
> [The Limbo Files, Volume 63, Issue 5](https://books.google.com/books?id=7t6iJ60J6RUC&pg=PA54&dq=%22love%20sight%20unseen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHo-XwibXTAhVSaVAKHW7UCBE4ChDoAQg5MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22love%20sight%20unseen%22&f=false)

---

> In the play Cyrano de Bergerac the beautiful Roxanne fell in love,
>   sight unseen, with a hideouslooking man who, beneath her balcony,
>   described a kiss as “A wish that longs to be confirmed, a rosy circle
>   drawn around the verb 'to love.
>
> [How to Create Chemistry with Anyone: 75 Ways to Spark It Fast--and
>   Make It Last](https://books.google.com/books?id=sYJKDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT72&dq=%22love%20sight%20unseen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHo-XwibXTAhVSaVAKHW7UCBE4ChDoAQhWMAk#v=onepage&q=%22love%20sight%20unseen%22&f=false)

---

> The basic plot was "Boy learns of girl and falls in love sight unseen;
>   boy meets girl; boy loses girl to a villain (resistant father or evil
>   suitor selected by her parents ); boy defeats villain (often with
>   girl's help); return to boy's home and marriage.
>
> [South Asian Folklore: An Encyclopedia : Afghanistan, Bangladesh,
>   India, Nepal, Pakistan, Sri Lanka](https://books.google.com/books?id=ienxrTPHzzwC&pg=PA6&dq=%22love%20sight%20unseen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHo-XwibXTAhVSaVAKHW7UCBE4ChDoAQgrMAI#v=onepage&q=%22love%20sight%20unseen%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

As above, this question suggests that you have a particular someone in mind, along with particular unrealistic expectations of them. That said, the word you're looking for is

## [the one](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/the_one)

> Another person regarded as one's destined life partner.

Answer (score 0):

***[Soulmate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/soul_mate)***

> A person ideally suited to another as a close friend or romantic
>   partner.

(Oxford)